# How can I sort a UITableView using CoreData information in swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data

I'm new to core data and I'm trying to sort my UITableView from data fetched from CoreData. I know how to do this using an array, but I'm struggling to find out how to do it with CoreData. I've read similar questions but it's either in Objective-c -which I haven't learned- or it's not solving my specific problem. My CoreData entity is named numbers and it stores numbers of type Float that the user passes in. My code here is in my viewDidAppear method, the first line is my declaration of myNumbers array which is globally available in that class. ***Take note that my entity has more than one attribute, I have an attribute "number" and an attribute "name" which is a string.

```
    var myNumbers: Array<AnyObject> = []

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let appDeleg: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDeleg.managedObjectContext!
    let fetchreq = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Numbers")

    //Would I be adding the sort descriptor here?
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "numbersAttribute", ascending: true)
    fetchreq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]

    myNumbers = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchreq, error: nil)!
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Now this is the code in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellID: NSString = "myCell"

    var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellID) as CustomCell

    if let indexpth = indexPath as NSIndexPath! {

        var data: NSManagedObject = myNumbers[indexpth.row] as NSManagedObject
        cell.theTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("tName") as? String

        cell.theDetailTextLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("tNumber") as? String

    }
```

I want to order the data in my table view based on the "tNumber" attribute in the Numbers entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using an `NSSortDescriptor`. Do the following before doing the fetch request to populate myNumbers.

```
// Note that the key is the attribute of your Numbers entity that you are sorting
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tNumber", ascending: true)
fetchreq.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptors]
```

This should work, but the best way to accomplish loading data from Core Data into a table is to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. This is especially true if you're dealing with a very large or transient data set.

Comment: note that OP wants to fetch entity named "Numbers", so probably `key: "numbers"` has to be replaced by the appropriate attribute name of `Number` entity.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I overlooked that clarification. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I've tried your solution (I appreciate the help), I've tried a few variations but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong and how all of this works.

Comment: You'll need to post more code then because there is nothing wrong with the code from this answer

Comment: Are you getting any values back from Core Data? Did you change the key in the NSSortDescriptor to match the attribute you set in your Numbers entity?

Comment: Bluehound, I've added more code, feel free to ask for more if you feel there is something missing. timgcarlson, my table view is working fine, data is displayed but not in the order I want them to be. And yes I did set the key in the sort descriptor to match the attribute I have in my entity. I've been trying to understand why it doesn't work but still can't get it.

Comment: Thanks for posting more code. Looks like you didn't change the key of the sort descriptor to the correct attribute (assuming what you posted above is what is in your code). You want to have the key be "tNumber" since that is how you set up your entity. I've updated my answer to show this. `let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "tNumber", ascending: true)`. Note the key is tNumber, which is the attribute you are looking to sort."